# How to sum data from the same table with different condition?

Tags: php, sum

I fetched some data from the same table name, but with different condition and I queried it 3 times and the result is :

```
101=>1
301=>1
501=>2
502=>4
---------------
101=>2
501=>1
---------------
101=>1
501=>1
```

which the first column is classrooms and the second column is values. What is the best way to sum those values with the same classroom so the result would be :

```
101 = 4
301 = 1
501 = 4
502 = 4
```

My query command:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(std_id) AS total, std_class  FROM attendance WHERE att_mode IN('mode-01','mode-04') AND att_attend='0' AND att_date=CURDATE()  GROUP BY std_class ORDER BY std_class");
    $query->execute();
    while ($char = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $labels2[] = $char->std_class.'-'.$char->total;
        $link[] = $char->std_class;
    }
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(std_id) AS total_sick,std_class FROM attendance WHERE att_mode ='mode-01' AND att_attend='2' AND att_date=CURDATE()  GROUP BY std_class ORDER BY std_class");
    $query->execute();
    while($char = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $sickCount[] = $char->std_class.'-'.$char->total_sick;
    }
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(std_id) AS total_leave,std_class FROM attendance WHERE att_mode ='mode-01' AND att_attend='3' AND att_date=CURDATE()  GROUP BY std_class ORDER BY std_class");
    $query->execute();
    while($char = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $leaveCount[] = $char->std_class.'-'.$char->total_leave;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. Instead of making query 3 times, I run only one query.
Working query is :

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(std_id) AS total, std_class FROM attendance WHERE att_mode IN('mode-01','mode-04') AND att_attend IN('0','2','3') AND att_date=CURDATE() GROUP BY std_class ORDER BY std_class");
```

The "WHERE" clause would meet the "att_mode" that contains value of '0','2', and '3'. Then I got a desired result.
Thanks for all previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using subquery.

```
"SELECT std_class , COUNT(std_id) as total ,(SELECT COUNT(std_id) AS total_sick FROM attendance WHERE att_mode ='mode-01' AND att_attend='2' AND att_date=CURDATE()  GROUP BY std_class ORDER BY std_class ) AS total_sick    , (SELECT COUNT(std_id) FROM attendance WHERE att_mode ='mode-01' AND att_attend='3' AND att_date=CURDATE()  GROUP BY std_class ORDER BY std_class) AS total_leave FROM attendance WHERE att_mode IN('mode-01','mode-04') AND att_attend='0' AND att_date=CURDATE()  GROUP BY std_class ORDER BY std_class "
```

If not working then let me know...

Comment: I got this error: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Priyank's answer is obviously better as it's done through SQL, so no PHP overhead.

I would take the result of each query, stick it into an associative array, and loop them. It would look like this:

```
$result = db_query1();
$total = array();
foreach ($result as $classroom => $value) {
    $total[$classroom] += $value;
}

$result = db_query2();
foreach ($result as $classroom => $value) {
    $total[$classroom] += $value;
}

$result = db_query3();
foreach ($result as $classroom => $value) {
    $total[$classroom] += $value;
}

print_r($total);
```

Answer (score 0):

*As mentioned, Priyank's answer should be the way to go, but since before seeing the other answers I wrote a little function for you I'll post it anyway since it might be useful if you don't want for any reason do it all in SQL.*

```
function mergeAndSum() {
    // get all the given arguments and put them into an array
    $arrays = func_get_args();

    // create an array that will contain the output
    $output = array();

    // loop through all the arguments
    foreach($arrays as $array) {
        // if an argument is not an array it will be skipped
        if(!is_array($array)) {
            continue;
        }
        // otherwise it will be iterated
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            // if the key is already in the $output array
            if(array_key_exists($key,$output)) {
                // add the value to the existing onve for that key
                $output[$key] += $value;
            } else {
                // else store in the $output array the key with it's value
                $output[$key] = $value;
            }

        }

    }

    return $output;

}
```

So, assuming you have you three array with the results of the queries

```
$link = array(
    101=>1,
    301=>1,
    501=>2,
    502=>4,
);
$sickCount = array(
    101=>2,
    501=>1
);
$leaveCount = array(
    101=>1,
    501=>1
);
```

you just pass them in

```
$output = mergeAndSum($link,$sickCount,$leaveCount);
```

and your $output will be as desired

```
(
    101 => 4
    301 => 1
    501 => 4
    502 => 4
)
```

Keeping in mind that the SQL way would be better, this function would be flexible enough to be used in other similar cases where you have some arrays to merge and sum